# Possibly fixing exception in Catch

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

Is it possible that I would bind a method and fix the error in the catch response? (for example take this code below)

```cs
try
{
    if (icheck == 0)
    {
        BindRegister();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Error Message";
    }
}
catch
{
    icheck = 0;
    BindRegister();
}
```

Is the catch just responsible for writing down the error message? (I'm using this code in my ASP.net web app)

Comment: When you run this code, what happens?

Comment: there are previous conditions that I checked on and if all conditions were satisfied, then icheck = 0. When icheck = 0, it calls the BindRegister() method. In case all conditions were satisfied and icheck !=0, it'll call the exception.

Comment: When you run **this code you posted**, what happens? Is it working as expected or does some unexpected happen?

Comment: no it works fine, no error happens, but I thought of using try and catch in case of any unexpected error

Comment: @Amir You say "in case all conditions were satisfied and icheck !=0, it'll call the exception" but it's not throwing an exception it's just setting a label.  Are there exceptions thrown by `BindRegister` and is there any reason to believe they will not occur again if it's run a second time?

Comment: Your try-catch has no point. The only thing in your snippet that could throw an exception is the BindRegister() method which is only called if the check value is 0. If BindRegister throws an exception, setting the same condition again and re-calling it is just going the throw a whole new exception again that won’t be caught. 

Try-catch blocks are there for the genuinely unexpected, if you believe that your code could break given a specific condition, then refactor and write to prevent it from happening to begin with before calling further code.

Comment: juharr - actually no, there are no exceptions in my method, so i guess the try-catch here is unnecessary

Comment: Stuart Frankish - Thank you so much for this clarification, so in this case i will remove the try-catch from where I used it in my code and place it (if necessary) in my BindRegister. However, i'd like to ask one more question, if an unexpected error occurred in my method and I threw a new exception, will this error occur once more?